# How to check file existance before upload to OneDrive using .Net or c#

Tags: c#, rest, duplicates, onedrive

I am going to upload my files from local PC to OneDrive using c#, I would need how to check the file existance before upload them.

Please suggest any has algorithm which is using by One Drive.

I have tried to create XORHash but it different.

Comment: start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0

Comment: Are you trying to check if the files exist locally or are you trying to see if they're already stored on the user's OneDrive?

Comment: I am trying to check on OneDrive.